# Special condition to change date format if date is given in particular format

Tags: php, cakephp

I am reading date field from excel file. I am able to read it successfully if date is a proper date. But in some cases i am having date like

**07.12.12**

As it is not a proper date format, **it should be 07.12.2012.**

**And my script reading it as 12-12-2007. But i want the output as 07-12-2012.**

So is there any way so that i can check if format is coming as dd.mm.yy (special case) then i can simply explode the values with using

**explode('.','07.12.12')**

and change the date according to my need.

Thanks

Comment: This is no Cake question, but primary of PHP. Read manual about Date, strtotime and strftime.

Comment: So the year given with two digits instead of four is your only problem? If that’s all (and single digits are always fronted by a 0) you could simple check the length of the date string …

Answer (score 1):

Use DateTime Object.

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d.m.y', '07.12.12');
echo $date->format('d.m.Y');
```

[CodeViper Demo.](http://codepad.viper-7.com/oQTHwk)

**Note:** I personally suggest you to keep date format standard (`d-m-Y`) which is separated by `-` & not by `.` Also this method will support only for PHP version >= 5.3.0.

**Edited:** Regexp condition to check if your date is in d.m.y

```
$pattern = '/^[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{2}$/';
if(preg_match($pattern,$date,$matches)){
   #conversion goes here    
}
```

Also you can use,

```
 if(substr_count($date,'.') == 2){
    #conversion goes here
 }
```

Comment: How do they tell when it is m.d.y and not d.m.y?

Comment: @JohnConde - In OP example `07` seems date. And if it is month one can change format in `createFromFormat` accordingly.

Comment: In their specific example, sure. But I'm sure they have more dates than just that one this needs to work for.

Comment: but rikesh my question was that if i am reading a date and first i will check if it is in format 07.12.12 then only i will use explode other wise i will simply read it using date('d-m-Y',strtotime('given date'))

Comment: @Dinesh In that case I think you need to first check your date format using regex. If it is in `d.m.y` format than use this otherwise as you said.

Comment: thanks rikesh can you please tell me the syntax of regular expression to check this , actually i have tried but not succeeded

Comment: @Dinesh - You can use `if(substr_count($date,'.') == 2)` condition.

Answer (score 0):

Just check on the length:

```
$pieces = explode('.', '07.12.12');
if (strlen($pieces[2]) !== 4) {
    $pieces[2] = '20' . $pieces[2];
}

// proper date in YYYY-MM-DD format
$date = $pieces[2] . '-' . $pieces[1] . '-' . $pieces[0];
```